# Is there a way how to navigate to destination and add another to backtstack in NavigationManager?

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

Hi I am new to android NavigationManager.

Consider fragments A, B and C conected in nav_graph as shown in the picture. [image: scheme]

Basically what I am trying to achieve is to navigate from fragment A directly to C. But when clicking on back button, I want it to behave as if I were first in fragment B.

So A->C,   on back buttons: C->B->A

Is there some way, how I could add fragment B to backstack without actually showing it using NavigationManager?

Comment: checkout my old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56270422/6376080) on this type question.

Comment: @NickBapu Thanks, but I was trying to do it without overwriting onBack method. That's why I specifically asked for solution using NavigationManager.

Comment: Look this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854105/custom-back-stack-for-each-fragment-in-tabhost-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems I should be more careful when reading documentation. I missed [this site](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back).

There is mechanism for custom back behavior. All I needed to do was to add this code to fragment C class:

```
//use onResume if you want to handle orientation change
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val callback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, object :
        OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            val options = NavOptions.Builder()
                .setPopUpTo(R.id.fragmentC, true)
                .build()

            navController.navigate(R.id.fragmentB, options)
        }
    })
}
```

My mindset was wrong the whole time. I was trying to add B to backstack when launching C. What I had to do instead in fragment C on back button pressed was going forward to B and delete C from backstack.